# Union with unequal number of columns in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I would like to know how it's possible to make a union/union all query using tables with unequal number of columns (say 3 and 4). 
I know that I can achieve this using ***NULL AS col*** in simple SQL.

However I am working in Laravel and I would like to know whether there is a possible way of doing this using **Query/Builder** or any other way.

Comment: Try selecting `NULL col` using fluent. It would probably work (or it may need `DB::raw("NULL col")`)

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me, with sql query builder of laravel 5.2

```
        $first = DB::table('user_prod')
            ->select('user_id', DB::raw("NULL as debit")) //shows 'null' because the 'debit' column does not exist in this table
            ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);

        $second = DB::table('user_transaction')
            ->select('user_id', DB::raw("debit")) //shows the value of the column 'debit' table 'user_transaction'
            ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)

            ->union($first)
            ->get();
```

dd($second);

Answer (score 0):

```php
$select = ['location_id', 'comment', 'rating', 'reviewer', 'channel', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
```

With select array above `DB::raw();` not worked for me.

Another (worked for me) solution is

```php
$first = ...->select('user_id', ...$select); // spread operator since php 7.4

$second = ...->select('NULL as user_id', ...$select);
```